# How to start "appendRow" in a specific column (Google Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I'm currently developing a script where I'm storing data in a spreadsheet, but I could't find a way to make sheet.appendRow() to start in a specific column, so the question is: Is there a way to do this?

Specifically, I want to set this

```
for(var i in keywordCeroClicks) {
    var keyword = keywordCeroClicks[i];
    var Fila=[];
    Fila.push(fecha, keyword);
    sheet.appendRow(Fila);
  }
```

to store the data starting at column 3 instead of column 1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add blank value :

```
for(var i in keywordCeroClicks) {
    var keyword = keywordCeroClicks[i];
    var Fila=[];
    Fila.push(fecha, keyword);
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),3,1,2).setValues([Fila]);
    //sheet.appendRow(Fila); //old code
  }
```

In the code snippet fecha is not defined.

Stéphane

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and it worked to some degree, but not quite as I've expected... the thing is that i've data in the first two columns, so adding blank values does start the data in the third column, but below the data i've in the first two columns, not next to it... anyway, I'm thinking it's not possible to do what I want with .appendRow... thanks a lot for your answer though!

Comment: Ok so append will not fit the need because append will always put data in the first line with no value so that is why putting blank data is not a problem because it is inserted in a new line. For your need you have to use the setValues() function it will be : sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),3,1,2).setValues([Fila]); I modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    sheet.appendRow([null, "a man", "a plan", "panama"]); 
}
```

The above example comes from:

Google Apps Script: appendRow(rowContents)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)

//null gets you to the next column, the more you add, the further out you go to the next column, please make sure you separate them by , (commas)